# Как в СУБД Firebird из скрипта вызвать другой скрипт?

Tags: sql, firebird, freepascal

Есть программа которая вызывает на выполнение первый скрипт,

как из первого скрипта вызвать второй?

script1.sql (для изменения структуры базы данных)

```
set term ^ ;

execute block
as   
begin
  execute statement '
  create table table1 (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  price INTEGER);';
end^

set term ; ^
```

script2.sql (для работы с данными)

```
insert into table1 (name, price) values ('рога', 1000);
insert into table1 (name, price) values ('копыта', 2000);
```

фрагмент кода программы на паскале(free pascal/lazarus)

```
Script.Script.LoadFromFile('script1.sql');
Script.Execute;
```

Мне хочется сделать главный скрипт который будет проверять структуру и содержимое базы данных,
а затем вызывать другие скрипты.

В одном скрипте не удобно, хочется разделить.

Comment: Дело в IBExpert/IBEscript происходит? Какого типа объект `Script`?

Comment: Дело происходит в моей программе, Script : TSQLScript. У меня не получается выполнить другой скрипт из первого скрипта и в IBExpert.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Вам придется в своей программе реализовывать алгоритм последовательной или условной загрузки и выполнения нескольких скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```pascal
Script.Directives.Add('LOAD');
Script.OnDirective := DoDirective;
Script.Script.LoadFromFile('script1.sql');
Script.Execute;

procedure TMyForm.DoDirective(ASender: TObject; ADirective, AArgument: AnsiString;
  var AStopExecution: Boolean);
begin
  if ADirective = 'LOAD' then
    ProcessScript(AArgument);
end;

procedure TMyForm1.ProcessScript(const AFileName: AnsiString);
var
  LScript: TSQLScript;
begin
  LScript := TSQLScript.Create(nil);
  try
    LScript.Script.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    LScript.Execute;
  finally
    LScript.Free;
  end;
end;
```

И в скрипте

```sql
LOAD data.sql;
```

Само собой вместо `LOAD` вы можете использовать любую другую директиву